# Clearing .net textbox controls not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a webform with lots of textboxes, i want to `string.Empty` all of them in the foreach statement simply as follows:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if(c is TextBox)
  {
      //..some code
  }

}
```

But the if statement is not returning true, although i have textboxes in the page. But when i try writing:
`if(c is Control)`, it returns true, Textbox don't.

Cound't see what im doing wrong.. Thanks for help

Comment: What is `this` in this context?

Comment: Could the text boxes be the children of another control?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Answer (score 1):

You're only looping through the immediate children of `this` which probably is the page object.

To loop through all controls on the page included the nested ones, you must recursively traverse the control tree.

```
public void RecursivelyClear(Control parent)
{
    for each (var theControl in parent.Controls)  {
        if (theControl is TextBox)
            // your code here ...
        if (theControl.HasControls)
            RecursivelyClear(theControl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
```

Comment: I tried this one, c.GetType().Tostring() returns System.Web.UI.LiteralControl

Answer (score 0):

Easiet way of resetting form is to add a RESET HTML button:

```
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

This way you will avoid a page postback and a loop through all of the controls. It will help enhancing page performance for just resetting controls.

I hope this will answer your question. If yes, then please mark as "answered".